# Inline кнопки. Программа жалуется на неправильно написанную строку

Tags: python, aiogram

Делаю инлайн кнопки для бота.
Не получилось из-за непонятной мне ошибки.

Открыл гайд, сделал "ctrl+c, ctrl+v",
Всё так же ничего не работает.

Жалуется на 18 строчку.

Господи...
Метоlом тыка решил это.

В гайде строчка выглядит так:

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(func=lambda c: c.data == 'button1')
```

Я просто убрал "func=", надеясь, что это поможет и... Помогло.

Вышло так: (Да ладно)

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == 'button1')
```

Comment: Может быть ошибку покажете?

Comment: Добавил. Криво.
Странно тут как-то работает правка...
Вторым скрином не хочет прикрепляться.